# Linux driver for Broadcom BCM943228HMB

Tags: linux, ubuntu, drivers, wifi-driver, broadcom

How do I install **broadcom BCM943228HMB 802.11abgn 2x2 WiFi** Adapter driver in Linux? My OS is Ubuntu 14.04. 
My previous laptop had a **Qaulcomm Atheros AR9285 802.11b/g/n WiFi** Adapter and Ubuntu could easily access it on its own.

Comment: In https://linux-hardware.org/?id=pci:14e4-4359-14e4-05e2&page=1#status BCM9443228 is marked "Working" in several systems with Ubuntu 16 - 20. No info whether it works on a release this old. It's supported on kernel 3.14 and newer. It's also supported with additional `wl` driver.

Answer (score 0):

Usually when dealing with Adapters that are not directly supported, the best option I have used is first to install a program called Ndiswrapper which allows  Linux to use Windows drivers for wireless card support.

After installing Ndiwrapper just Open the "Windows Wireless Drivers" service from the

System -> Administration menu:

Then locate a .inf file similar to the following image when you choose "Install new Driver"

[image]

After the installation you can simply  choose what the device from your list of networks.

Answer (score 0):

Qualcomm Atheros AR9285 802.11b/g/n is better than Broadcom BCM943228HMB 802.11abgn, because the drivers are free (as in freedom). See  https://h-node.org/wifi/catalogue/en/1/1/undef/undef/undef/undef/wifi-works/undef?search_string=AR9285&submit=Search

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: How is that relevant to the question?